# GoogleAuthException: Unknown

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android#step_2_turn_on_the_api_name

I am trying to access excel sheet using this link.
Getting error

```js
e = {GoogleAuthIOException@6455} "com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException"
 backtrace = {Object[15]@6457} 
 cause = {GoogleAuthException@6458} "com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown"
 detailMessage = null
 stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[0]@6459} 
 suppressedExceptions = {Collections$EmptyList@6460}  size = 0
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@6239} "class com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -2073870077
```

Comment: Please don't post external links or images of text. Cannot be searched, and cannot be copied.

Comment: Post your code here instead of this Image. How are you trying to access?

Comment: @VicJordan please check the Link in Question.